# EF core join statement is incorrect

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a class Product

```cs
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? PreferredProductVersionId { get; set; }
    public ProductVersion PreferredProductVersion { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductVersion> ProductVersion { get; set; }
}
```

With configuration

```cs
public class ProductConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Product> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(s => s.ProductId);
        builder
            .Property(s => s.ProductId)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .IsRequired();
        builder.Property(s => s.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

        builder.HasMany(s => s.ProductVersion)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.ProductId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
    }
}
```

And a class ProductVersion

```cs
public class ProductVersion
{
    public int ProductVersionId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public Guid Code { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

With configuration

```cs
public class ProductVersionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductVersion>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductVersion> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(s => s.ProductVersionId);
        builder
            .Property(s => s.ProductVersionId)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .IsRequired();
        builder.Property(s => s.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasColumnType("varchar(50)");

        builder.HasOne(s => s.Product)
            .WithOne(s => s.PreferredProductVersion)
            .HasForeignKey<Product>(s => s.PreferredProductVersionId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull)

    }
}
```

So a Product can have multiple ProductVersions, a Productversion belongs to one product.
A product also has one PreferredProductVersionId, which indicates which ProductVersion should be selected by default.

I then have a piece of code that fetches me the ProductVersion by ID, which includes the Product

```cs
public ProductVersion GetProductVersion(int ProductVersionId)
{
    return _appDbContext.ProductVersion
        .Where(x => x.ProductVersionId == ProductVersionId)
        .Include(x => x.Product)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This results in the following query

```sql
DECLARE @__ProductVersionId_0 int = 151;

SELECT [p].[ProductVersionId], [p].[Code], [p].[Name], [p].[Position], [p].[ProductId], [p0].[ProductId], [p0].[Name], [p0].[PreferredProductVersionId], [p0].[ProductCategoryId]
FROM [ProductVersion] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [Product] AS [p0] ON [p].[ProductVersionId] = [p0].[PreferredProductVersionId]
WHERE [p].[ProductVersionId] = @__ProductVersionId_0
```

The LEFT JOIN here is wrong, I want this instead:

```sql
DECLARE @__ProductVersionId_0 int = 103;

SELECT [p].[ProductVersionId], [p].[Code], [p].[Name], [p].[Position], [p].[ProductId], [p0].[ProductId], [p0].[Name], [p0].[PreferredProductVersionId], [p0].[ProductCategoryId]
FROM [ProductVersion] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [Product] AS [p0] ON [p].ProductId = [p0].ProductId
WHERE [p].[ProductVersionId] = @__ProductVersionId_0
```

I realise I need to be more explicit on the relationships in the configuration but everything I try seems to be failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem, you need add another `Product` property to `ProductVersion` and then reference that property instead of your current `Product` one. As it's using the foreign key that you defined when doing the relationships.

Change `ProductVersion` to have `ProductWithVersion` property.

```
public class ProductVersion
{
    public int ProductVersionId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }

    public Guid Code { get; set; }

    public Product Product { get; set; }

    public Product ProductWithVersion { get; set; }
}
```

Change your relationship to:

```
builder.HasMany(s => s.ProductVersion)
        .WithOne(x => x.ProductWithVersion)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.ProductId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Change your query to:

```
return _appDbContext.ProductVersion
    .Where(x => x.ProductVersionId == ProductVersionId)
    .Include(x => x.ProductWithVersion)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some duplicate data. Would be enough just use a flag IsPreferred. I would change the classes

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductVersion> ProductVersions { get; set; }
}
public class ProductVersion
{
    public int ProductVersionId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public bool IsPreferred { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public Guid Code { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

and you can use the same query

```
public ProductVersion GetProductVersion(int ProductVersionId)
{
    return _appDbContext.ProductVersion
        .Where(x => x.ProductVersionId == ProductVersionId)
        .Include(x => x.Product)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```